# Delete repos from DevOps "My Organizations"

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, repository

I'm using tfs to save a project inside "My Organizations" in Azure DevOps.

I've succeded, now I can commit my project.

During this process I left some "corpses" and I have no idea on how get ride of them.

I cannot delete them inside VS and if I enter on "My Organizations" only the working project is visible.

Why this repos aren't visibile on My Organizations list ?

[image]

Comment: repos are under projects, they cant be visible from this page

Comment: If I go under Organization Settings -> Projects the only one that I can see is "Gighub", I really don't understand where those with the gibberish names are stored.

Comment: under another account, perhaps?